# Form Submission Works from Curl but Not Browsers - No Errors Logged

Tags: php, forms, apache, post, require

I asked a question similar to this one a few days ago but nobody was able to answer me apart from suggesting I contact my hosting provider's support. They aren't any closer to fixing the issue and say it is an issue with my code.

**The facts are these:**
 - HTML is fully valid
 - CSS is fully valid
 - PHP is reported as being syntactically correct
 - No JavaScript is present on the page
 - The required file is being found by the require statement
 - No errors are being logged
 - This is not a case sensitivity issue
 - **This works on my localhost (Ubuntu 12.04) and a Raspberry Pi but not on my external hosting provider's servers**
 - **When submitted from Curl, the file is included and all works perfected but from the browser, nothing happens**

**Code:**

*Requirement of small external file:*

```
if((require 'contactFunctions.php') == 'OK')
    echo "Included";
else
    print_r(error_get_last());
```

The above jumps to the else (tested with a simple error string) but doesn't print and errors as none are reporting. Error logging works fine (tested by missing a semi colon, or incorrect file name) and will report usually.

*If Statement to run code if form has been submitted*

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

*Form*

```
<form id="enquiryForm" method="post" action="contact.php">
```

*Submit Button*

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Enquiry" />
```

Any ideas as to what is going wrong with this would be extremely appreciated. I've asked around and researched for about three days now and I'm still no closer to fixing this issue. The code worked fine for months up until about three days ago when it just stopped working on my host's servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved.

Recently, a member of my team implemented a .htaccess file on the website but failed to update the form action attribute from "contact.php" to "contact"

This was the cause of the strange behaviour of the site and why submission only worked from curl which sent the request directly to contact.

Answer (score -1):

Your requirment checking wrong. Please try next one:

```
<?php
  try {
    if (!@include_once('contactFunctions.php'))
      // @ will suppress warnings
      // use include or include_once for checking
      throw new Exception ('contactFunctions.php does not exist');
    else
      require_once('contactFunctions.php');
      // you can change to require or include
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    // catching error
    print_r($e);
    // or your variant
    print_r(error_get_last());
  }

  echo "Done";
?>
```

If statement for submission checking looks like good.

Comment: I have managed to resolve my issue but thank you for the tips regarding requirement checking.

Comment: @vascowhite Lol. Did you noticed "try"?